# Why is Path.Combine better than "\\"?

Tags: c#, string

Over the years, and again recently, I have heard discussion that everyone should use Path.Combine instead of joining strings together with "\\", for example:

```
string myFilePath = Path.Combine("c:", "myDoc.txt");  
// vs.  
string myFilePath = "C:" + "\\myDoc.txt";
```

I'm failing to see the benefit that the former version provides over the latter and I was hoping someone could explain.

Comment: Run this code on Linux and see what you get!

Comment: Also, please be aware that `Path.Combine` [treats starting slashes in its own way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748032/why-does-path-combine-produce-this-result-with-a-relative-path).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Building a path with `Path.Combine` is more readable and less error-prone. You don't need to think about directory separator chars(`\\` or `\` or `/` on unix, ...) or if the first part of the path does or does not end in `\` and whether the second part of the path does or does not start with `\`.

You can concentrate on the important part, the directories and filenames. It's the same advantage that `String.Format` has over string concatenation.

Comment: I've lost count of the number of times I've seen paths with double backslashes in, because people didn't use `Path.Combine()`. It's a good job that the Windows API ignores extra backslashes in paths (other than at the start of a path)!

Comment: How does unix come into play?  This probably sounds silly, but as a .NET developer, at what points are my applications running on unix?

Comment: OK, That's what I thought.  I guess I haven't gotten around to messing around with that yet.

Comment: @DarrenHale Gotcha.  While I have started using it, it is way less readable than concatenating slashes.

Comment: @A.R.: You find `Path.Combine(root,sub1,p2,p3,p4,p5,fileName)` less readable than `root + "\\" + sub1 + "\\" + p2 + "\\" + p3 + "\\" + p4 + "\\" + p5 + "\\" fileName`? Not to mention that you need to maintain  it or to find bugs if one of the variables contains incorrect slashes.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, I find it much less readable.  Readability is a matter of opinion.  The rest of the answer is objective, and I am now using Path.Combine (even though I have never had a problem doing it manually)

Comment: @A.R.: "How does unix come into play? This probably sounds silly, but as a .NET developer, at what points are my applications running on unix" With  .NET Core you can develop for multiple platforms

Answer (score 9):

When you don't know the first directory (e.g. it comes from user input), you may have `C:\Directory` or `C:\Directory\` and `Path.Combine` will solve the trailing slash problem for you. It does have quirks with leading slashes for the next arguments though.

Second, while usually not a problem for most applications, with `Path.Combine` you aren't hard-coding the platform directory separator. For an application that can be deployed to other operating systems than windows this is convenient.

Answer (score 4):

Other platforms can use a different Separator, for example `/` instead of `\` so the reason for not using `\\` is to be S.O. independent

Comment: S.O. ? do you mean O.S.?

Answer (score 3):

In this case, it does not really matter, but why don't you just write:

```
string myFilePath = "C:\\myDoc.txt";
```

The Path.Combine() method is useful if you are working with path variables and you don't want to check for backslashes (or whatever slashing required, depending on the platform):

```
string myFilePath = Path.Combine(path, filename);
```

Comment: It was a contrived example.