# Path.Combine not working when combining remote server path with a file path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, path-combine

From an ASP.NET MVC app I am trying to concatenate two paths, a remote server path with a path extracted from database. I am performing below:

```
string serverPath = @"\\myServer\TempFolder";
string filePath = GetPathFromDatabaseTable();

string finalPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(serverPath, filePath);
```

GetPathFromDatabaseTable method returns this string:

```
\\path\\to\\file.pdf
```

When concatenating using Path.Combine, the result got into finalPath is:

```
\\path\\to\\file.pdf
```

So the prefix serverPath \myServer\TempFolder is removed. Why is happening?

Comment: omg just ran into this converting to net6 from framework. works on linux boxes though

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Uri` class to achieve combining a remote and a local path:

```
string serverPath = @"\\myServer\TempFolder";
string filePath = "\\path\\to\\file.pdf";

Uri serverUri = new Uri(serverPath + filePath);

string finalPath = serverUri.LocalPath;
```

Which returns

```
\\myserver\TempFolder\path\to\file.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the query returning `\\path\\to\\file.pdf` exactly? or is that only a representation in c# debugger.

You should **not** store `\\` as directory separator into the database field. the `\\` is only needed to escape the string when you write it in c#.  *(unless you are using the `@"\"`)*

If you use `\\` in the database field, the first `\\` will be seen as a rooted path and probably removes the previous path.

Comment: In database it is stored with single back slashes, I mean, \path\to\file.pdf

Comment: But the `\ ` in-front of the `\path\to\file.pdf`, refers to the root.

Answer (score 0):

Dropping the leading slash at the beginning from filePath works as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748032/why-does-path-combine-produce-this-result-with-a-relative-path) in the solution.

so if in database is stored as \path\to\file.pdf then when I read from database I drop the leading slash at the beggining, so GetPathFromDatabaseTable method returns:

```
path\\to\\file.pdf
```

instead of:

```
\\path\\to\\file.pdf
```

so then when combining using System.IO.Path.Combine it works perfectly.